# Que evento tengo que usar para visualizar datos de un DataGrid de una celda seleccionada?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

Hola como estan? Tengo un metodo que me esta funcionando bien pero en realidad no es lo que espero.

```
        private void dgFleteros_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dgFleteros.CurrentRow;
        tbNombre.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value);
        tbVehiculo.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Value);
    }
```

Esto funciona cuando el usuario hace click en la grilla, pero yo lo que necesito es que me muestre los datos de la celda que esta seleccionada actualmente, sin necesidad de hacer click.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Perdon por no aclarar, es una aplicacion de windows form en visual studio y c#

Comment: Es asp.net Web forms?.. podrías hacerlo del lado del cliente con javascript...

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo si te fijas en el evento figura como " DataGridView" por lo que está hablando de winforms. En asp se llama "gridview" . Saludos!

Comment: Tienes razon (Y)

Comment: Si es WinForms, deberia ser el on focus del row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude resolverlo! Olvide aclarar algo en el enunciado de la pregunta.
Cuando hice doble click en el diseño de la grilla, automaticamente visual studio te crea el metodo con el evento de clickear la celda.

Lo que hice fue buscar las referencias del metodo que crea visual studio y cambiarle el evento alli

Este es el que crea:

```
this.dgFleteros.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dgFleteros_CellContentClick);
```

Y esto es lo que necesitaba:

```
this.dgFleteros.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dgFleteros_CellContentClick);
```

El metodo que ya estaba hecho queda igual, solo que hay que reemplazar el segundo parametro por EventArgs e

No se si es la mejor solucion pero al menos funciona como quiero.

Gracias por sus respuestas!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias formas de hacerlo, pero te voy a mostrar la mas sencilla. En el caso de tener desactivada la selección múltiple o si solo deseas obtener la primera de toda la selección, lo podrías hacer así:

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0] // obtienes la fila seleccionada.
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index // obtienes el indice de la fila seleccionada.
```

Si tienes la selección múltiple activa y deseas obtener mas de una fila para generar un reporte por ejemplo, puedes recorrer la lista con un for. Quedaría algo así el código:

```
// contador de filas seleccionadas.
Int32 selectedRowCount =
        dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
    if (selectedRowCount > 0) // Si hay filas seleccionadas...
    {
       // Recorremos el listado de filas seleccionadas
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowCount; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Index;
            // Obtienes el indice y realizas las acciones para cada uno
            // por ejemplo guardar los id en un array, cambiar un valor, etc...           
        }

    }
```

Tambien puedes revisar la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/selected-cells-rows-and-columns-datagridview). Saludos!

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta! Pero creo que no es lo que busco, o no me funciono o no lo hice bien, ja! En realidad, el codigo que puse yo es lo que quiero que pase, pero no cuando el usuario haga click en la grilla, sino que muestre en los textbox siempre el valor de la celda seleccionada. No seria un tema del evento? Perdon, recien empiezo a programar.

Comment: no hay problema, de a poco se aprende. En realidad si es un tema de eventos y ahora entendiendo bien lo que necesitas yo te recomendaría usar el evento [SelectedIndexChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) ya que hay veces que se cambia la selección por otros factores que son ajenos al click de un usuario. Saludos!